# How to show soft keyboard on Android Things?

Tags: adb, android-softkeyboard, android-things

I'm trying to show soft keyboard on *Android Things*, *Raspberry Pi 3*. I tried the methods below, but not succeeded so far:

```
<activity
       ...
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
```

and

```
<EditText
        ...
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Does *Android Things* 7.0 support soft keyboard, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`Update II`**: [there is a bug with Dev Preview 5.1 when Google's soft keyboard doesn't show up at all](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+CarlWhalley/posts/X3KnPu3JVGe?cfem=1).*

***`Update`**: starting with Dev Preview 4 the Android Things image is shipped with `com.google.android.inputmethod.latin` preinstalled. If you're going to use a 3d party keyboard app the approach below is still valid.*

---

You should enable the IME in *Android Things Developer Preview* in order for it to show up. Let's consider `Google Keyboard` as an example (since it worked for you). Once the keyboard has been installed and you **`shell`-ed in** (with `adb shell`) the following options might be used:

---

### *Command line solution*

- **Find out the IME ID**

  ```
  $ ime list -a | grep mId
  ```
- **Enable the IME using the fully qualified mId**

  ***Android Things 0.5+*** (*you might get `already enabled`*)

  ```
  $ ime enable com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
  ```

  ***Android Things 0.1 - 0.4*:**

  ```
  $ ime enable com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME
  ```

*Note: If you'd like to use the IME "app-wide" (not "system-wide"), use `ime set ID` instead of `ime enable ID`*.

---

### *Settings app solution*

***Android Things 0.5+*:**

```
    am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$SystemDashboardActivity
```

**`Languages & Input`** -> **`Virtual keyboard`** -> **`Manage keyboards`** and enable the IME (*should already be enabled*)

***Android Things 0.1 - 0.4*:**

```
    am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$InputMethodAndLanguageSettingsActivity
```

**`Virtual keyboard`** -> **`Manage keyboards`** and enable the IME

*Note: In order to close _Android_'s settings app from within `shell` you can emulate a back button press multiple times with `input keyevent 4` or force close the app with `am force-stop com.android.settings`*.

Comment: I tried AT0.5.1. Soft keyboard does not show up again in all cases described above.

Comment: @Ibrahim ERTURK, the solutions are fine. [It's a bug in AT 0.5.1](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+CarlWhalley/posts/X3KnPu3JVGe?cfem=1)

Comment: None of this seems to work on 6.1 unfortunately... Does 6.1 require different steps? Or did it inherit the 5.1 bug?

Comment: @Stefan Haustein, if you get the `already enabled` message when enabling the IME as per the answer, then I believe the bug has been inherited.

Comment: Yes, get the "already enabled" answer. The bug is marked as fixed here though: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68768712

Comment: @Stefan Haustein, good reference! It states: _"Soft keyboard package added back in DP6"_, but the package had already been added in DP 5.(0/1) which was stated above. So yet I believe the bug has been inherited.

Answer (score 2):

By default, keybord apps are not installed on *AT Developer Preview*. You have to install it. See [software keyboard](https://plus.google.com/+AdamBrownW/posts/WCEvcGrhra9).