# How to request permission on Android Things?

Tags: android, permissions, android-things

I'm trying to write to a value on AT. I've already declared required permission as follow in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

And try to request permission at run-time, AT shows windows regarding permission setup. However the switch is not clickable. Regarding AT [document](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html)

> Requesting Permissions at Runtime is not supported because embedded
>   devices aren't guaranteed to have a UI to accept the runtime dialog.
>   Declare permissions that you need in your app's manifest file. All
>   normal and dangerous permissions declared in your app's manifest are
>   granted at install time.

However `Settings.System.canWrite()` always returns `false`.

Are there any special methods to enable permission `WRITE_SETTINGS`?

Comment: On ordinary Android devices, [that permission requires a double-opt-in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/115145), including the user granting the permission in Settings. I do not know what the long-term plan is for permissions like this with Android Things, given that the user may not have any way to work with the Settings app (e.g., no screen).

Comment: Please file a bug regarding your issue obtaining the permission you need to access the Settings API: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20bug%20report

Comment: @Devunwired I don't have developer account. So I can't access the service android issues.

Comment: @IbrahimERTURK All you need is any Google account, which you will need sooner or later if you plan to continue developing on any Android-based platform.

Comment: Did you able to find solution for write settings in AT with preview 0.4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After install application with the statement on `AndroidManifest.xml` as follow

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

It needs to be also run `Settings` as follow via `adb`

```
adb shell am start -S com.android.settings/.Settings
```

Then click `APPS>YOUR_APP`, then click `permission`.

Now the switch is clickable. So AT not granted to permission. It needs to be granted manually.

Comment: There is no such activity on Android Things.

Comment: The answer is valid for AT version dev 0.3. It may be changed for AT 1.0 stable version.

Answer (score 9):

Like you said, the documents say:

> Declare permissions that you need in your app's manifest file. All normal and dangerous permissions declared in your app's manifest are granted at install time.

Therefore you don't see the normal Android permissions UI.

From the release notes:

> Dangerous permissions requested by apps are not granted until the next device reboot. This includes new app installs and new  elements in existing apps.

So try powering off and on your Android Things device

Comment: According to boot up messages `W/PackageManager: Unknown permission com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in package com.android.onetimeinitializer`. Does the message says, there is no way to write to setting on AT?

Comment: I've tried to power on and off. Still, No grant to access settings. @Blundell

Comment: I don't think the current version of Android things has System Settings.

Comment: @ierturk have you tried after Android Studio 3.0 was released? should work as Blundell said

Comment: @eOnO this is not regarding version of Android Studio. However, I tried AT up to 5.3, so it need to be granted by user manually. So it needs to be a display and keyboard, or touch screen display to grant permission. Also, with AT 4 and 5.3, there is a bug with  AOSP soft keyboard. I have to switch back to version 3. have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015209/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-on-android-things#comment80073645_42033832)

Comment: thanks for the clarification @ierturk i didn't knew that.

Comment: to show app permissions: `adb shell dumpsys package <package name or applicationId>`

Answer (score 0):

This permission is having `Protection level: signature`.Which means this permission is only granted to **system apps**.

Please find the below screenshot for your reference :

[image]