# Soft keyboard with Android Things on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things, android-input-method

I'm running Android Things 1.0.4 on a Raspberry Pi with a [Touch Display](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/) and the soft keyboard is never displayed, even when giving focus to an input field.

For instance, in the wifi system settings I cannot enter the SSID password.

I found this question: [How to show soft keyboard on Android Things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015209/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-on-android-things). But when running the command:

```
ime enable com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
```

I get a "already enabled" result:

```
Input method com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME: already enabled
```

What can I do to make the keyboard show up?

Comment: There is a soft keyboard included in the OS by default, although I'm not really sure why it's not showing up in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the keyboard didn't show up because there was a plugged USB device (NFC reader) which was obviously considered by the system as a hard keyboard.

The soft keyboard worked again after unplugging the device.